# What can I improve to make a responsive design

Tags: html, css

When resizing the <p > tag breaks out of its parent <div>, how can I
make it responsive and stay in the <div> HTML code. That's what I
want to achieved with HTML and CSS: I tried to wrap everything in a div so I can control elements using absolute elements so I can center it in the middle.

Thank you in advance for your advices to help me make nicely written websites in the future.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Didact+Gothic');
    

    html,body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #eee;        
        }
        header {
            height: 100vh;
            background-size: cover;
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
            background-image: url("/images/background.jpeg")
        }
        .text {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .text1 {
            font-size: 35vh;
            position:absolute;
            top: 5%;
            left: 5%;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin: 0;
            height: auto;
        }
        .text2 {
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 35vh;
            position:absolute;
            left:33%;
            top: 40%;
            font-size: 5vh;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        .text3 {
            position:absolute;
           left: 15%;
            top: 50%;
            width: 50vh;
            height: auto;
            margin: 0;
            font-weight: 4vh;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-style: italic;
            font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
            color: #fff;
        }
        .text4 {
            position:absolute;
            left: 15%;
             top: 65%;
             margin: 0;
             width: 50vh;
             font-weight: bold;
             font-style: italic;
             color: #fff;
             font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
        }
```

```html
<header id="showcase">
<div class="text">
<h1 class="text1">-20%</h1>
<h1 class="text2">Rabbat</h1>
<p class="text3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui.
 </p>
 <p class="text4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui.
</p>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: In addition to @tosta's comment, you would do well to not use `position: absolute;` so much. The whole point of responsive design is to let elements reflow freely in all viewport sizes.

Comment: thank you i will keep that in mind

Answer (score -1):

Use this in your head  tag, and try not to use absolute positions for inner controls

```
<style>
p{
   work-break: break-all;
}
</style>
```